# Difference between next and step in "byebug"

Tags: byebug

What the difference between "step" and "next" in "byebug".
When should one use one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

step: Step execution into the next line or method. Takes an optional numeric argument to step multiple times.

next: Step over to the next line within the same frame. Also takes an optional numeric argument to step multiple lines.

Please check through `pry-byebug` gem documentation for futher details:

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug#commands

Answer (score 0):

For people who'll see this question afterwards, as the current answer to the question didn't explain the difference between two commands in more depth (to me at least as a one who still in the beginning steps of learning ruby).

Please refer to the following blog post [Debugging with pry-byebug: moving in the stack frame](https://remimercier.com/pry-byebug-intermediate) which helped me learn the difference with an **example**.